# How to click on JS Alert by using GeckoFX

Tags: c#, winforms, gecko, geckofx

I have a geckoWebBrowser control, it works well. But I stucked at somewhere, the webpage that I navigated alert like this

"Do you really want to do something bla bla? [OK] [NO]"

How can I click on OK?

Comment: "Using the mouse" is _probably_ not the answer you are looking for?

Answer (score -1):

Use AutoJSContext

```
    GeckoWebBrowser browser = ....;

    using (AutoJSContext context = new AutoJSContext(browser.JSContext))
    {                               
     string result;
     context.EvaluateScript("3 + 2;", out result)
    }
```

Comment: I couldn't understand. How can I use that function? Couldnt find any source on the web about usage